# How can i make python take a data time in format hh:mm:ss and store it in an array?

Tags: python, time, format

I have a list of csv file which contains several columns.
There's one that contains the lenght of my test in this format hh:mm:ss
I need to divide this data in two database based on lenght: <00:16:00 or >00:16:00
How can I do that? 
Thanks for helping and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: google stuffs before asking please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brute force:

```
value = "00:15:47"  # taken from csv

if value < "00:16:00":
    # handle smaller values
else:
    # handle bigger values
```